# Mercurial diff not working after move/rename

Tags: version-control, mercurial, diff, dvcs, rename

After moving a file into another directory I cannot display the differences between two revisions any more. E.g.:

```
hg init

touch a
hg add a
hg ci -m "Added a"

echo "Bli" >> a
hg ci -m "Bli"
echo "Bla" >> a
hg ci -m "Bla"
echo "Blub" >> a
hg ci -m "Blub"

hg diff -r 0 -r 1 a
```

Results in:

```
diff -r 8603b08f5a64 -r 16675581549e a
--- a/a Mon Apr 23 09:03:25 2012 +0000
+++ b/a Mon Apr 23 09:03:25 2012 +0000
@@ -0,0 +1,1 @@
+Bli
```

which is what I expected. However when I now move the file "a" into a directory "b":

```
mkdir b
hg mv a b/a
hg ci -m "Moved a into b"
cd b
hg diff -r 0 -r 1 a
```

this results into nothing (no output at all). I also tried to use the git Giff algo:

```
hg diff --git -r 0 -r 1 a
```

Again, there is no output at all. The log is seems to be OK:

```
hg log --follow a
```

Results in:

```
changeset:   4:cb8185829bfd
tag:         tip
user:        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
date:        Mon Apr 23 09:08:12 2012 +0000
summary:     Moved a into b

changeset:   3:4d1ba89885c3
user:        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
date:        Mon Apr 23 09:03:26 2012 +0000
summary:     Blub

changeset:   2:e9126dbb50b2
user:        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
date:        Mon Apr 23 09:03:26 2012 +0000
summary:     Bla

changeset:   1:16675581549e
user:        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
date:        Mon Apr 23 09:03:25 2012 +0000
summary:     Bli

changeset:   0:8603b08f5a64
user:        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
date:        Mon Apr 23 09:03:25 2012 +0000
summary:     Added a
```

Has someone any idea why the diff is not working after moving a file? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: BTW: I'm using Mercurial 2.2-rc

Comment: I edited the question slightly: Mercurial doesn't track directories, so `hg add b` doesn't do anything when `b` is an empty directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is difficult or impossible with today's Mercurial. I think the closest you can get is

```
hg log --follow --patch -r 1 a
```

where Mercurial will track the copies backwards (`--follow`) before showing the diff (`--patch`).

In general, Mercurial does not track **file identities**, it only tracks **file names**. When you lookup information by revision number, Mercurial will first lookup the revision, and then lookup any filenames in that revision. So `hg cat -r 0 a` will give you the same result as

```
hg update -r 0
cat a
```

i.e., the result is independent of the current working directory parent.

Comment: Thanks again, Martin. This explains the behaviour. The work around via log --patch is nice for the console. If I have time I will look into MercurialEclipse and see if there is a possibility to hack in this work around.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's because `b/a` doesn't exist in revision 1 or revision 0.  If you execute the command `hg diff -r 0 -r 4` from within the `b` folder it should produce the expected output.

If you execute `hg diff -r 0 -r 1 a` from the root of the working copy it should also show the expected output.

Comment: Right. This does not only sound reasonable but also seems to answer my question. Unfortunately, it does not solve my problem. After converting from CVS to Mercurial there is a directory containing a bunch of files which should be rather in the root folder. Now I can't move them into the root folder without loosing a directly accessible history (via MecurialEclipse). I.e. I want to access the revision differences in Eclipse via "Right Click" --> Team --> History --> "Select two revisions" --> "Right Click" --> "Compare to each other".