# Mercurial move followed by diff

Tags: mercurial

I had two very large projects in my Mercurial repository.
I am in the process of refactoring both of them into smaller sub-projects.
That involves moving sets of sources from a parent project directory into a sub-project's sub-directory.
For most files, I simply moved them.
For some files, I also had to make changes.
Before I commit my refactoring changes, I would like to review any edits that I made to any source files. In the GUI tool SourceTree - it shows me any modifications (in addition to indicating that the file has been moved/renamed). Is there any way to determine what files have also been modified from the Mercurial command line?

Here is a specific example of what I am talking about:

iphonedev:EveryScape cdoucette$ hg status -C Engineering/iOS/ESSDK/src/ESSDK-Miscellaneous/ESDataManagerInMemory.m
A Engineering/iOS/ESSDK/src/ESSDK-Miscellaneous/ESDataManagerInMemory.m
  Engineering/iOS/ESSDK/src/ESDataManagerInMemory.m

How can I compare the old revision with the current working copy in a different location?

If I just do this:

```
hg diff Engineering/iOS/ESSDK/src/ESSDK-Miscellaneous/ESDataManagerInMemory.m
```

It shows me the entire contents of the file (since technically it was added in its new location).

Instead, I want to diff between:

1. Engineering/iOS/ESSDK/src/ESDataManagerInMemory.m (repository copy - previous revision)
2. Engineering/iOS/ESSDK/src/ESSDK-Miscellaneous/ESDataManagerInMemory.m (working copy)

I did search for similar questions. This post was close - but appears to only make sense if I went ahead and committed my changes. Instead, I would like to find and review my changes before committing.
[Mercurial diff not working after move/rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10277773/mercurial-diff-not-working-after-move-rename)

Answer (score 1):

I would script it up like this:

```
hg cat -r <oldrev> <oldfilename> > oldfile.oldrev

diff <newfilename> oldfile.oldrev
```